# Filtering QuerySets by OR instead of AND

Tags: django, django-models

If I do:

```
People.filter(name = 'Oscar', lastName = 'Mederos)
```

it will be translated to something like:

```
SELECT ______ WHERE Name = 'Oscar' AND LastName = 'Mederos
```

Does Django allow to do the same but using `OR` instead of `AND`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
People.objects.filter(Q(name='Oscar') | Q(lastName='Mederos'))
```